# RegEx - Match Character only when it's not proceeded or followed by same character

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I match the quotations around "text" in the string below and not around "TEST TEXT" using RegEx. I wanted just quotations only when they are by themselves. I tried a negative lookahead (for a second quote) but it still captured the second of the two quotes around TEST TEXT.

```
This is some "text". This is also some ""TEST TEXT""
```

Be aware that I need this to scale so sometimes it would be right in the middle of a string so something like this:

```
/(\s|\w)(\")(?!")/g (using $2...)
```

Would work in this example but not if the string was:

```
This is some^"text".This is also some ""TEST TEXT""
```

I just need quotation marks by themselves.

### EDIT

FYI, this needs to be Javascript RegEx so lookbehind would not be an option for me for this one.

Comment: Honestly, I'd preprocess. Remove all instances of `""`, then extract.

Comment: @EvanKnowles I like that idea. How do you think about my solution (see my answer) compared to yours? While my solution does work, I'm thinking you should post yours as it may work better.

Comment: Yours keeps the `""` though, so I think that's more like what he's after.

Comment: @MxmastaMills I don't understand the down vote but can you clarify if my answer is what you need. If not I'll delete it

Comment: @fede, that down vote was not me FYI. I'll be taking a look at this in the morning when I start work and will let you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I really understood well your needs. I'll post this answer to check if it helps you but I can delete it if it doesn't.

So, is this what you want using this regex:

```
"\w+?"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fG5vH2/1)**

By the way, if you just want to get the content within `"..."` you can use this regex:

```
"(\w+?)"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fG5vH2/3)**
[image]

Comment: Umm this will only match word characters between double quotes. OP didn't mention this as requirement since stated requirement was to grab only string like `"..."` but ignore `""...""`. Not trying to take anything away from the answer but I suspect it is case of a not-so-well-written problem.

Comment: @MxmastaMills thanks for the tick. I don't understand why someone downvoted if the answer is to help, anyway... thanks.

Comment: Hi @anubhava no worries, thanks to clarify. Anyway, I don't understand why someone downvotes... even if an answer is wrong I wanted to help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not tagged any particular flavor of regex I am takig liberty of using lookbehind also. You can use:

```
(?<!")"(?!")[^"]*"
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vX8qN3/1)

**Update:** For working with Javascript you can use this regex:

```
/""[^"]*""|(")([^"]*)(")/
```

And use captured group # 1 for your text.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vX8qN3/4)

Comment: @MxmastaMills FYI, added a JavaScript solution

Comment: Hey anu, I've been curiously watching your updated solution: How does it work?

Comment: If you click on demo link and then see `MATCH INFORMATION` on bottom-right you will see captured groups finds exactly what OP intends to find. This is a simple regex technique where lookbehind isn't allowed. Here we select whatever we don't want on LHS of alternation (pipe) and leave the part that we want in rightmost part in captured groups.

Comment: @anubhava While that would work after post-match algorithm, OP states "_I just need quotation marks by themselves._" How would this help OP match the brackets by themselves?

Comment: @Unihedron: This regex: `""[^"]*""|(")([^"]*)(")` will give just that. [You can see this demo](http://regex101.com/r/vX8qN3/4)

Comment: Excellent, it works now. Maybe you can add that into your answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a pure JavaScript regexp. I am going to eat my words now however, as you can use the following solution using callback parameters:

```
var regex = /""+|(")/g
replaced = subject.replace(regex, function($0, $1) {
    if ($1 == "\"") return "-"; // What to replace to?
    else return $0;
});
```

> ```
> "This is some -text-. This is also some ""TEST TEXT"""
> ```

If you're needing the regex to split the string, then you can use the above to replace matches to something distinctive, then split by them:

```
var regex = /""+|(")/g
replaced = subject.replace(regex, function($0, $1) {
    if ($1 == "\"") return "☺";
    else return $0;
});
splits = replaced.split("☺");
```

> ```
> ["This is some ", "text", ". This is also some ""TEST TEXT"""]
> ```

> Referenced by:
> http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html