# JavaScript regular expression split by space only in certain context

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the string: `word word{test test}`

How can I split this into an array like:

```
["word", "word{test test}"]
```

I want to split by space but ignore the space inside the curly braces

Comment: So you want to split on all spaces that don't have "test" either side?

Comment: Or do you want to ignore spaces inside curly braces?

Comment: You've given a rather ambiguous example - could you please attempt to define exactly what you are trying to do? What are the exact requirements?

Comment: I want to ignore the spaces inside the curly brace.  I'm sorry if my phrasing was ambiguous

Comment: Hey @Unihedron, thanks for your solution.  I don't think your missing anything, it solves the problem.  I'm going to give the correct answer to Chris B.  His solution seems to be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of thinking about this as a split, I think it's easier to think about it as a match. The following is the RegEx I've concocted. The line of code you can use is:

```
str.match(/[^\s]*{[^}]*}[^\s]*|[^\s{}]+/g)
```

To break it down more readable there are two parts. The first:

```
[^\s]* { [^}]* } [^\s]*
```

it says any number of non-whitespace followed by a { followed by anything that isn't a } then a } then any number of non-whitespace. So I think you'll have to assume that every start brace is capped. Not sure if you can assume that or not. If you need to match nested braces then you need to use something more powerful than Regex/FA because it does not have state.

The second part is

```
[^\s { }]+
```

saying match one or more of any non whitespace/non curly brace item.

Here is a jsfiddle showing the code. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djh5ydan/2/)

Comment: Just came to post a similar solution. Here is my regex:
[A-Za-z]+\{.+\}|[A-Za-z]+/g;

Comment: This works pretty well. Thanks.  I don't think you need the '|' in the second part however.

Comment: Thanks, glad it works, and I think you're right about the second half only needing to be [^\s]+

Comment: -1 The pattern `[^\s|^{|^}]+` shows a lack of basic regex knowledge.

Comment: Mind sharing what you don't like about that pattern? Here is a regexr example showing that the last two ORs aren't useless. http://regexr.com/39akm

Comment: An `|` inside a `[^]` means "don't match `|`". Same with the `^` that are not at the front.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the feedback. That's much more helpful than your previous comment. I've corrected the syntax above to (hopefully) achieve my original intent.

Comment: I'm thinking the { should be escaped as well.  Can anyone confirm that?  It should be: /[^\s]*\{[^}]*}, or is that not the case since it follows a * ?  Also my earlier comment was in reference to me thinking you were usings the | as or's.  I never realized or forget that ^ negates the whole thing: good to know :)

Comment: It seems like escaping can't hurt and that javascript is likely being lenient considering we aren't using the curly bracket in the form {number}.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a pure JavaScript regex. I am going to eat my words now however, as you can use the following solution using callback parameters:

```
var regex = /{[^}]+}|( )/g
replaced = subject.replace(regex, function($0, $1) {
    if ($1 == " ") return "\0";
    else return $0;
});
splits = replaced.split("\0");
```

> ```
> >>> subject = "word word{test test}"
> ... "word word{test test}"
> >>> var regex = /{[^}]+}|( )/g
>     replaced = subject.replace(regex, function($0, $1) {
>         if ($1 == " ") return "\0";
>         else return $0;
>     });
>     splits = replaced.split("\0");
> ... ["word", "word{test test}"]
> ```

**Read more:**

- [RegEx - Match Character only when it's not proceeded or followed by same character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25091949/3622940)
- [The Best Regex Trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Answer (score -1):

It's not foolproof, but you can split on one or more space characters only if there is no `}` before a `{` ahead in the string.

```
var str = 'word word{test test}';

str.split( /\s+(?![^{]*})/ );   
// ["word", "word{test test}"]
```